New kitchen faucet lost water pressure after running dishwasher
Ugh. So we had some issues with our dishwasher. I ended up fixing those and the dishwasher is now running normally.
Now, our kitchen sink has lost hot water pressure,  it's just a trickle. We checked the pressure at the valve, no issues. So hubby replaced the valve and the line. Also got a new kitchen faucet. After the new faucet was installed, there was water pressure again!
Then after a dishwasher load ran, we lost COLD water pressure!
We've back flowed both hot and cold water lines, cleaned the aerator, and checked the cartridge.
I decided to switch the water supply hoses so that they were going to opposite valves and found that only one supply hose was not flushing; if connected to cold, no cold water pressure,  if connected to hot,  no hot water pressure.
I'm at a loss of how to fix this. We've flushed the lines and even used a hose to push water through.
Do I have to buy yet another faucet? When running the dishwasher, did it kick debris up into the water supply hose and it got stuck somewhere where it cannot get out?
The loss of water pressure is only at the kitchen sink.

It sounds like debris/something is in the pipes.  Turn off the main water valve and remove the shutoff valves(one at a time).  Use a bucket and turn on the main valve(two person job).

you are missing a filter on dishwasher line
